# Programmatically position ggplot labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a lot of charts programmatically in R using ggplot2 and have everything working perfectly except the position of bar labels.

This requires inputs of the plot height, y axis scale and text size.

**Example (stripped down) plot code:**

```
testInput <- data.frame("xAxis" = c("first", "second", "third"), "yAxis" = c(20, 200, 60))

# Changeable variables
yMax <- 220
plotHeight <- 5
textSize <- 4

# Set up labels
geomTextList <- {
  textHeightRatio <- textSize / height
  maxHeightRatio <- yMax / height

  values <- testInput[["yAxis"]]

  ### THIS IS THE FORMULA NEEDING UPDATING
  testInput[["labelPositions"]] <- values + 5 # # Should instead be a formula eg. (x * height) + (y * textSize) + (z * yMax)?    
  list(
    ggplot2::geom_text(data = testInput, ggplot2::aes_string(x = "xAxis", y = "labelPositions", label = "yAxis"), hjust = 0.5, size = textSize)
  )
}

# Create plot
outputPlot <- ggplot2::ggplot(testInput) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(data = testInput, ggplot2::aes_string(x = "xAxis", y = "yAxis"), stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
  geomTextList +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, yMax, yInterval), limits = c(0, yMax))

ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "test.png", plot = outputPlot, width = 4, height = plotHeight, device = "png")
```

I have tried various combinations of coefficients for the formula, but suspect that at leat one of the factors isn't linear.  If this is purely a statistical problem, I could take it to Cross-Validation, but I wondered whether anyone had already solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is with offsetting the text to not overlap the bar while dealing with varying text sizes, just use `vjust` which is already proportional to the text size. A value of `0` will make the bottom of the text touch the bar, and a small negative value will give you some space between them:

```
testInput <- data.frame("xAxis" = c("first", "second", "third"), "yAxis" = c(20, 200, 60))

# Changeable variables
yMax <- 220
plotHeight <- 5
textSize <- 4

# Set up labels
geomTextList <- {

  values <- testInput[["yAxis"]]

  testInput[["labelPositions"]] <- values # Use the exact value
  list(
    ggplot2::geom_text(
      data = testInput,
      # vjust provides proportional offset
      ggplot2::aes_string(x = "xAxis", y = "labelPositions", label = "yAxis"),
      hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.15,  size = textSize
    )
  )
}

# Create plot
outputPlot <- ggplot2::ggplot(testInput) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(data = testInput, ggplot2::aes_string(x = "xAxis", y = "yAxis"), stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
  geomTextList +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, yMax))
ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "test.png", plot = outputPlot, width = 4, height = plotHeight, device = "png")
```

Comment: Thank you - this definitely solves the problem I posted.  My actual issue was a bit more complicated, but this led me to the solution!